# How to not require spaces in ANTLR4

Tags: parsing, antlr4, context-free-grammar, text-parsing, lexical-analysis

I am using ANTLR4 to try and parse the following text:

```
ex1, ex2: examples             
var1,var2,var3: variables
```

Since the second line does not have whitespace after the commas, it doesn't parse correctly. If I add in the whitespace, then it works. The rules I am currently using to parse this:

```
line : list ':' name;
list : listitem (',' listitem)*;
listitem : [a-zA-Z0-9]+;
name : [a-zA-Z0-9]+;
```

This works perfectly for lines like line 1, but fails on lines like line 2, if there are parenthesis or pretty much any punctuation, it wants some whitespace after the punctuation and I can't always guarantee that about the input.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First add explicit lexer rules (starting with a capital letter). Then add a lexer rule for whitespace and ignore the whitespace:

```
 line : list ':' name;
 list : listitem (',' listitem)*;
 listitem : Identifier;
 name : Identifier;


 Identifier : [a-zA-Z0-9]+; // only one lexer rule for name and listitem, since and Identifier may be a name or listitem depending only on the position

 WhiteSpace : (' '|'\t') -> skip;
 NewLine : ('\r'?'\n'|'\r') -> skip; // or don't skip if you need it as a statement terminator
```

Comment: Okay thanks, that helps. Can you explain to me the difference between different capitalizations of rules? I didn't realize that it made a difference...

Comment: Lexer rules start with capitalized letters, parser rules with lower case. Lexer creates tokens, parser gathers tokens. Have a look at sample grammars and/or read the book.